# The first setSpan didn't work

Tags: android, spannablestring

```
final StyleSpan bss = new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD);
final SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("How to " + text + " in " + type);
ss.setSpan(bss, 7, text.length() + 7, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
ss.setSpan(bss, 7 + text.length() + 4, ss.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(ss);
```

I want to make `text` and `type` **BOLD**. But only type is BOLD.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the documentation :

> `setSpan(Object what, int start, int end, int flags)`
>   Attach the specified markup object to the range start…end of the text, or move the object to that range if it was already attached elsewhere.

A `StyleSpan` can only be used once in a `Spannable`. You need create a StyleSpan for each `text` and `type`

Comment: I just spent over an hour trying to figure out why my styling disappeared whenever I added more than a few stylings, until I found out that it removed the first styling and stuck it to the last appearance of that specific appearance.
FYI: This part of the documentation only shows up on the `Spannable` class and not the children of the class, which makes this almost impossible to figure out.
Good job figuring this out and not so nice a job on Google's behalf removing/not making the classes inheriting the documentation...
As to why I can't reuse an appearance more than once, I don't know...

Comment: Presumably because the identity of the style object is used as the key for looking up span boundaries; see, e.g., `Spanned#getSpanStart(Object tag)`. The documentation should really make this a lot clearer. It was only because I figured `get` couldn't possibly work if the style objects were reused that I guessed that this was the case, and found this answer to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

You should create object like below.

```
ss.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), 7, text.length() + 7, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
ss.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), 7 + text.length() + 4, ss.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(ss)
```

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is to use the static method instead of create several Objects:

```
CharacterStyle.wrap(CharacterStyle c)
```